# Finding record when price last lower and last higher and last equal within large dataset with SQL

Tags: sql, max, where-clause, impala

I am really sorry if this is not a smart question but I have very basic coding skills.

The example dataset is:

```
Price| Period | Desc1 | Indicator
1.6  | 202006 | item1 | Food
1.5  | 202007 | item1 | Food
1.3  | 202008 | item1 | Food
1.5  | 202009 | item2 | Drink
1.3  | 202006 | item2 | Drink
1.6  | 202007 | item2 | Drink
1.4  | 202008 | item2 | Drink
1.5  | 202009 | item1 | Food
```

If we assume current period/latest period is 202009, What I am looking to achieve is an sql query which will help identify when the price was last lower than current, when it was last higher and when it was last equal.

I tried by using the following:

```
Select *
From Prices
where Price > (select price from Prices where period = max(period)) 
where Desc1 = "item1";
```

With this sql I was hoping to return the row where the price for item 1 was larger than the latest period price. So in this case return row:

```
1.6| 202006| item1| Food
```

And similarly change the operator to < and = to give me the values of when it was last lower and equal to the current price.

Please can someone advise what I am doing wrong? I have researched a lot and am short on time therefore posting on here.

Thanks,

Emelia

Please can

Comment: Please tag pour question with the database you are running: mysql, oracle, postgresql...?

Comment: You can't have two WHERE clauses like that. You probably want to AND the conditions.

Comment: The subquery is invalid too. You can't put MAX() in the WHERE clause like that.

Comment: Hi the database is Hive/Impala. Most mysql syntax tends to work I find.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this (this query would be to get lower price than current) :

```
SELECT
  b.*
FROM
  Prices a
  JOIN Prices b ON a.Desc1 = b.Desc1
WHERE
  a.Desc1 = "Item1"
  AND a.Period = (SELECT MAX(Period) FROM Prices WHERE Desc1 = "Item1" GROUP BY Desc1)
  AND a.Price > b.Price;
```

Alias "a" correspond to the line you want to compare (most recent periot price)

Alias "b" correspond to all the other lines concerning the product you want to compare

After joining the two, you just have to compare the 2 columns "Price" value.

Comment: Its not working for me- I am getting a blank table when I follow this. Another suggestion i have is can I create a view with prices table and create a new column 'price_current' and then compare the two?

Comment: Did you replace"Item1" by "item1" ? What result you got if you remove the a.Period condition in the WHERE statement ?

Comment: Ok this worked- i had to tweak it to my data- but i have finally understood the use of the alias. I was confusing myself a bit with the join. So thank you very much again! I also got rid of the (SELECT MAX(Period) FROM Prices WHERE Desc1 = "Item1" GROUP BY Desc1) and replaced by a.period = "202009" for user to specify as I was getting a syntax error. But this is fine. thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation.  Here is one method that does all the comparisons in a single row:

```
select p.*,
       max(case when price > price_202009 then period end) as period_gt,
       max(case when price < price_202009 then period end) as period_lt,
       max(case when price = price_202009 and period < 202009 then period end) as period_eq
from (select p.*,
             max(case when period = 202009 then price end) over (partition by item) as price_202009
      from prices p
     ) p
group by item;
```

If you want all the rows in a single query, then one method is:

```
select p.*
from (select p.*,
             max(case when period = 202009 then price end) over (partition by item) as price_202009
      from prices p
     ) p
where p.period = (select max(p2.period)
                  from prices p2
                  where p2.item = p.item and
                        p2.price < price_202009
                 ) or
      p.period = (select max(p2.period)
                  from prices p2
                  where p2.item = p.item and
                        p2.price > price_202009
                 ) or
      p.period = (select max(p2.period)
                  from prices p2
                  where p2.item = p.item and
                        p2.price = price_202009 and
                        p2.period < 202009
                 ) ;
```

The three conditions respectively get the period for each item where the price is less than, greater than, and equal to the 202009 price.  This can also be expressed using window functions, but your query is using a subquery so I used that method.